# Jdbc Odbc Connection Error

Tags: java, odbc, ms-access-2007

I m  working on a project. I have to establish database connectivity using Microsoft access file. when I am running the code there are bundles of exception displayed on dialog box. Please help me
here is the code...

```
    package uclidit;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    public class RegistrationForm extends 
    javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {                                                                      
    public String FullName,DOB,EmailId,PermAdd,TempAdd,MobileNo,Pincode;
    public String Rno;
    public int RegisterNo=1;


    public RegistrationForm() {
     initComponents();
     setVisible(true);
     setSize(700,700);
     setLayout(null);
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    }


           @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        dateChooserCombo1 = new datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 153, 153));
        setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1000, 1000));
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 800));
        setType(java.awt.Window.Type.POPUP);

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Algerian", 2, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        jLabel2.setText("Registration Form");

        jLabel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 153, 153));
        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Registration No :");
        jLabel1.setDebugGraphicsOptions(javax.swing.DebugGraphics.FLASH_OPTION);

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Date :");

        jTextField1.setEditable(false);
        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField2.setEditable(false);

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("To be filled by candidate ");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Full Name :");
        jLabel5.setToolTipText("");

        jTextField3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("DOB :");

        dateChooserCombo1.setNothingAllowed(false);
        try {
            dateChooserCombo1.setDefaultPeriods
          (new datechooser.model.multiple.PeriodSet());
        } catch (datechooser.model.exeptions.IncompatibleDataExeption e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        dateChooserCombo1.setFieldFont(new java.awt.Font
        ("Times New Roman",  java.awt.Font.PLAIN, 15));

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText("Mobile No. :");

        jTextField4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setText("Email Id :");

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setText("Perm.Add :");

        jLabel10.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel10.setText("Temp.Add :");

        jTextField5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea2.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Next");
        jButton1.setName("Next"); // NOI18N
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton2.setText("Cancel");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel11.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel11.setText("Pincode :");

        jTextField6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 12)); // NOI18N



        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

     private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        Rno=jTextField1.getText();

        if (evt.getSource() == jButton1) {
            int x = 0;

            FullName = jTextField3.getText();          
            //DOB = dateChooserCombo1.getText();          
            MobileNo = jTextField4.getText();

            EmailId = jTextField5.getText();

            PermAdd = jTextArea1.getText();

            TempAdd = jTextArea2.getText();

            Pincode = jTextField6.getText();
        }
        try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            String database="jdbc:odbc:Temp";
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(database,"",""); 
            PreparedStatement pstm = con.prepareStatement("insert into 
            Registration values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            pstm.setString(1,Rno);
            pstm.setString(3,FullName);
            //pstm.setString(4,DOB);
            pstm.setString(5, MobileNo);
            pstm.setString(6,EmailId);
             pstm.setString(7,PermAdd);
              pstm.setString(8,TempAdd);
               pstm.setString(9,Pincode);
               pstm.executeUpdate();
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"successful");
               con.close();

        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            StackTraceElement[] error=e.getStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                   error);

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(RegistrationForm.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,
           null, ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                   "In class not found");
        }

        }

     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");


      }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        this.dispose();
    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new RegistrationForm();
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info :   
          javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {   }   



            catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                 } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    }
        //</editor-fold>
        //</editor-fold>

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new RegistrationForm().setVisible(true);

            }
        });

    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private datechooser.beans.DateChooserCombo dateChooserCombo1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
    // End of variables declaration

}
```

and the errors shown are:

```
enter code here
java.sql.SQLException: No data found
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7137)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLDriverConnect(JdbcOdbc.java:3072)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.initialize(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:323)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.connect(JdbcOdbcDriver.java:174)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
at  uclidit.RegistrationForm.jButton1ActionPerf                                                         
at uclidit.RegistrationForm.access$100(RegistrationForm.java:10)
at uclidit.RegistrationForm$2.actionPerformed(RegistrationForm.java:134)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
atjavax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:234    1)
atjavax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java    :402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
atjavax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListen    er.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:686)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
atjava.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.    java:76)
atjava.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.    java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:700)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
atjava.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.    java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:699)
atjava.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.ja    va:242)
atjava.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:    161)
atjava.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.ja    va:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JDBC driver MS Access connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626301/jdbc-driver-ms-access-connection)

Answer (score 0):

I could not find in your code where is your Access file.

Please, look at this questions:

1. [JDBC driver MS Access connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626301/jdbc-driver-ms-access-connection)
2. [Connecting a Microsoft Access Database to Java using JDBC and compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320623/connecting-a-microsoft-access-database-to-java-using-jdbc-and-compiling)